# URL for Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, raphael

I want to use [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) in my blog. I want import it from another source as I can't host it on blogger. Do we have any site like [Google code](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html) which hosts Raphael.js?
Couldn't find it on Google code.

Comment: **Try [Raphael CDN](https://pagecdn.com/lib/raphael).**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[cdn js has it](http://www.cdnjs.com/#/search/raphael).

Currently their the latest version is:
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js

Answer (score 2):

Raphael has moved to https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael, get your
source code there.

Or use it through CDNJS: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/raphael

Or move on to http://snapsvg.io/

Answer (score 0):

[Raphael CDN](https://pagecdn.com/lib/raphael) is also provided by PageCDN. Here is embedable code for the current version:

```
<script src="https://pagecdn.io/lib/raphael/2.3.0/raphael.min.js" integrity="sha256-TabprKdeNXbSesCWLMrcbWSDzUhpAdcNPe5Q53rn9Yg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```